# Index Rebuild option not appearing in Sitecore Control Panel

Tags: sitecore-client, coveo

I am using `Coveo 4.0 Cloud platform with Sitecore 8.2`. I don't see an option for Index Rebuild in Sitecore control panel(Please refer attached screenshot).

Kindly let me know how to rebuild indexes.
[image: ve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coveo Index can build similar to the Sitecore indexing, in the control panel, under the indexing section click on Indexing Manager. Here you can see the Coveo indexes list with other Sitecore indexes.

[image]

Check you Coveo indexes and click on rebuild button.

**Update**: With the latest version of Coveo you will get the indexing manager, which will give you a UI interface to rebuild the indexes but with your current version Coveo 4.0 Cloud platform with Sitecore 8.2, you will not get this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore Control Panel you can see Indexing Manager in Indexing section as well. Try building your coveo indexes from there.

[image]

Comment: with Coveo 4.0 Cloud platform with Sitecore 8.2 you will not get the Indexing manager

Comment: that's why i said Indexing manager from indexing section and not form coveo search section. are you saying that indexing manager gets removed from indexing section as well?

Comment: No, it was for Coveo search section, and my answer is the same as yours.

Comment: Our answers were not same, we explained from our own unique perspective, and we posted at same time.